# Prevent function from being called in constructor while mocking, Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class that, when being constructed, cannot call a certain method.

```
public class ClassA() {
    @NonNull
    private ClassB b;

    public ClassA() {
        this.b = (new ClassC()).mymethod();
    }
}
```

I need to test ClassA without calling ClassC().mymethod() because calling it will throw an error. What is the best approach to do so? I tried @InjectMocks for ClassA with @Mock ClassC but it gives me null exceptions.

Comment: You want to create an object of type `ClassA` without the constructor being called?

Comment: @Progman, no, just the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refactor your class to make it more testable. The additional two constructors in the following code snipped can be used in tests with mocks for ClassC or ClassB:

```
public class ClassA() {

    @NonNull
    private ClassB b;

    public ClassA {
       this(new ClassC());
    }

    public ClassA(ClassC c) {
        this(c.mymethod());
    }

    public ClassA(ClassB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

**Example test case:**

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ClassATest {

  @Test
  public void test() {

    ClassB b = mock(ClassB.class);
    // ... setup your mock for b

    ClassC c = mock(ClassC.class);
    when(c.mymethod()).thenReturn(b);

    ClassA a = new ClassA(c);
    // ... call the method of "a" you want to test
  }
}
```

Comment: So with this you would do InjectMocks ClassA and Mock ClassC?

Comment: I'm still getting an error. I'm doing InjectMocks ClassA = new ClassA(); and Mock Class C with a Mock.doReturn on c.mymethod(). Is this correct?

Comment: @Goldname: I've added a sample test case. Please read the Javadoc of Mockito.doReturn, before you use it. Most of the time Mockito.when is the better choice. I would also suggest to avoid usage of InjectMocks whereever possible. Keep things simple and stupid ;-)

Comment: I gave it a try again with your method, but when(c.mymethod()).thenReturn(b); is still executing the real c.mymethod(). Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Also, just to be clear, I'm sticking with @Mock annotation isntead of mock(Class...) for the sake of consistency with the rest of the code, but it shouldn't be any different right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CALLS_REAL_METHODS` to avoid call constructor of `ClassA`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassATest {

    @Mock
    private ClassB b;

    private ClassA classA;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        classA = mock(ClassA.class, org.mockito.Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
        whitebox.setInternalState(classA, "b", b);
    }

   @Test
   public void shouldDoSomething() {
       // your test
   }
}
```